# Codelite with Debug on 'Executable' and Release on 'Static Library'

Tags: c++, git, static-libraries, executable, codelite

I am using CodeLite (version 11.0.0) on Ubuntu 16.04 to develop a static library.

I configured the Debug mode to produce an executable and I made a `main.cpp` file to call functions in my library and test them.

The goal of the project is however to produce a static library. I have already asked [how to make a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851515/how-to-compile-a-static-library-with-codelite-11-0-0), and I'm now aware of how to do that. The problem is, the solution I was proposed involved having a separate project for making the library.

This comes with annoyances, as I am developing source files in one project, and would need to make use of them in another one. After a couple of tedious copy-paste-and-debug exercises, I tried to set a Release mode to produce a static library out of the same source files.

The problem though is that I don't know how to tell CodeLite to build `main.cpp` in Debug, but ignore it in Release.

Debug folder should be:

```
main.cpp
module1.h
module1.cpp
module2.h
module2.cpp
library1.h
```

Release folder (to build a static library) should be:

```
module1.h
module1.cpp
module2.h
module2.cpp
library1.h
```

How do I tell CodeLite to use two different lists of source files when in different configurations? CodeLite stores this information in `xml` format inside a `.project` file:

```
<![CDATA[00020001N0005Debug0000000000000001N0007Release000000000000]]>
    </Plugin>
  </Plugins>
  <Description/>
  <Dependencies/>
  <VirtualDirectory Name="src">
    <File Name="main.cpp"/>
    <File Name="module1.h"/>
    <File Name="module1.cpp"/>
    <File Name="module2.h"/>
    <File Name="module2.cpp"/>
    <File Name="library1.h"/>
  </VirtualDirectory>
```

The same file also stores all dependancies. I thought of modifying it somehow, until I realised the file is automatically updated in the moment the configuration is changed from Debug to Release or vice versa.

Other thoughts I had were to somehow create a new project, or an entire workspace, in the same folder where all my files are held, and to have separate Git repositories or submodules in the same folder, using `.gitignore` smartly. However, they didn't seem neither elegant nor reliable solutions.

Is there a way I can have a single repository and project configurations in CodeLite to properly being able to both develop and test (running an executable called by `main`) and build a static library (excluding `main`) without needing to write and maintain CMake files?

Comment: Why don't you link that static library into your test project instead of copypasting code?

Comment: @VTT That's what I am trying to do, but building an executable (what I do with testing) is not the same as building a library. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that you need two (2) projects, one is static library with relevant code and another one - test executable that links static library from first project. You may also want to add third - "example" - project demonstrating typical use of your static library.

Comment: @VTT, now I follow. Basically it's what I mentioned in the second-last paragraph, but without needing 2 repositories. I'll give it a try

Comment: @VTT, it worked. There was no need of copy-pasting, and I now realise that was supposed to be done like this since the beginning... Thank you